# How to link a button to other xml in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, hyperlink

How to link a button in Android ?

for example in the Home page there are 2 buttons : 'Item1 & item2'

and i need to put in the code so i can click the 'Item' button and the Item1 data will be displayed ...

this is my current code on Activity.java :

```
    package com.example.myshops;

    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
            Home_fragment hf=new Home_fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, hf);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button item1Click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Item1Button);
            itemClick1.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button item2Click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Item2Button);
            itemClick2.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button item3Click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Item3Button);
            itemClick3.setOnClickListener(this);


            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());

            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            // formattedDate have current date/time
            Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


          // Now we display formattedDate value in TextView
            TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
            txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+formattedDate);
            txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            txtView.setTextSize(20);
            setContentView(txtView);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */

        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }



            public void item1Click(View view) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();     
                Item1_fragment hf=new Item1_fragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, hf);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }   


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 switch(v.getId())
      {
       case R.id.Item1Button:

         break;
       case R.id.Item2Button:

         break;
       case R.id.Item3Button:

         break;     
       }

        }


        }
```

my home.xml (for example) :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.myshops.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Item2Button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Item2Button"
            android:onClick="item2Click"
            android:text="@string/Item2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Item3Button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Item2Button"
            android:onClick="item3Click"
            android:text="@string/Item3" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Item1Button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="item1Click"
            android:text="@string/Item1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/PrevButton"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/Previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/HomeButton"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/Home" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/NextButton"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/Next" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

**error in my logcats :**

```
04-11 15:56:54.915: D/dalvikvm(547): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-11 15:56:56.145: D/AndroidRuntime(547): Shutting down VM
04-11 15:56:56.155: W/dalvikvm(547): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.s0237600_diary/com.example.myshops.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at com.example.myshops.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
04-11 15:56:56.165: E/AndroidRuntime(547):  ... 11 more
04-11 15:56:58.955: I/Process(547): Sending signal. PID: 547 SIG: 9
04-11 15:57:02.035: D/AndroidRuntime(565): Shutting down VM
04-11 15:57:02.035: W/dalvikvm(565): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myshops/com.example.myshops.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-11 15:57:02.055: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you once again explain what you are really tring to do

Comment: It's very simple. implement Item1Button click event and fetch data in onclick Item1Button and set as Text to Item2Button

Comment: @Sreekanthss there are 3 buttons in the home page , and i would like to display whats inside the item1 if the button are clicked ... but all the button doesnt work , and even worst the application always fail to running (when i double clicked the app , its stopped)

Comment: can you able to try by writing click  view for the button ?

Comment: If you are getting any error then please post your logcat error also.

Comment: @Sreekanthss can u give me the example

Comment: i have write a answer, try that.

Answer (score 0):

You should either define the click listener in code or in the xml not both. Remove one of them and the other should work.

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/Item3Button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Item2Button"
        android:onClick="item3Click"
        android:text="@string/Item3" />


remove this line from all of them        android:onClick="item3Click"

Comment: just the onclick line from every xml ?

Comment: Yes.. and you should get the button click in the onclick method.

Comment: wait you said i should remove the onClick .. then what do you mean by get the button click in the onclick method ? 
sory just got confused

Comment: you have set the listener to "this" in the code. so you should get the button click in the onclick method which you have overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Use

Onclicklistener like

```
 Button item1Click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Item1Button);

 item1Click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

and same for other button

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //check here that to which view does v match for example
    if(v==item1Click)
        {
            //then do something
        }
}
```

or else you can remove that implements thing and create separate listeners for each button as stated by raj

Answer (score 0):

Access your all the `Button` click listener using single click listener and use the id of your buttons and implement each click events as below:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  switch(v.getId())
  {
   case R.id.Item1Button:
     //write your logic
     break;
   case R.id.Item2Button:
     //write your logic
     break;
   case R.id.Item3Button:
     //write your logic
     break;     
   }
}
```

Comment: @GrlsHu now the issue is i cant run my app ... 

this is the error that i found from the debug :

 } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to start activity " + component
                    + ": " + e.toString(), e);

Comment: Please post your full logcat in your question @user3514625

Comment: @user3514625 Why are you again setting your layout with `TextView` in line `setContentView(txtView);`. If you set your layout again then you won't be able to access your buttons anymore as you have already changed your layout.

Comment: even after i remove it im still unable to run the app ... cant copy my logcat as well..

Comment: and for the //write your logic part i dont understand either , do u want me to type a code in there ?
because im not that good in programming ..

Comment: Yes you can write the code in that part whatever functionality you want to perform. Why you are not able to copy your logcat error ?

Comment: i dont know what should i write , can u give me example ? like i want that button to send me directy to other xml page when is clicked .... and the logcat has been posted in my questions ..

Comment: Press `ctrl+G` and write 44 it will redirect you to that line.

Comment: can u tell me other way beside the CTRL + G ? bcs im using mac .. and when i pressed ctrl+G it doesnt work anything .. @GrIsHu

Comment: Do one thing just remove the code of `FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
        Home_fragment hf=new Home_fragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, hf);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();` from your `onCreate()` and then try to run project. And check.

Comment: still not working ... the app stopped once is clicked

Comment: Show me your code. What have you done. Update your code in your question.

Comment: @user3514625 Dear you have inflated your layout in your activity ` setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` that is `activity_main` and you have metioned in your question that the buttons resides in your `home.xml` file. If your `Buttons` are in `home.xml` then you must inflate that layout as `setContentView(R.layout.home);`

Comment: yeah just modified it .. but still not able to click the button :( , the app stopped once i click the button. ...

Comment: Remove the property `android:onClick="item2Click"` from all your buttons in your layout.

Comment: still not working at all ... @GrIsHu
it shows error on the Console : 
[2014-04-11 16:38:17 - myshops] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myshops/.MainActivity }
[2014-04-11 16:38:17 - myshops] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Answer (score 0):

i am telling one way to the solve the issue, there are other ways too to solve the issue

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/Item3Button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Item2Button"
        android:onClick="item3Click"
        android:text="@string/Item3" />
```

here you have written  `android:onClick="item3Click"`, for all button,

so in the jave code you can write like

```
 public void item3Click(View view){

    //what ever you want to do in the button 3 click 
    }
 public void item2Click(View view){

    //what ever you want to do in the button 2 click 
    }
 public void item1Click(View view){

    //what ever you want to do in the button 1 click 
    }
```

repeat the same for the all button,